# Android TV Google Play Services Keep Crashing | Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: crashes, google-play-services, android-tv

On my Raspberry Pi 3, I am running Android TV 6.0 Marshmellow ([From this tutorial](http://geektillithertz.com/wordpress/index.php/2016/06/02/android-tv-for-raspberry-pi-3/)), and gApps from [This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-rpi/X075avZy-wM) (Second Post Down), but for some reason, Google Play Services keeps stopping. I've tried clearing the cache for Play Services, but that did nothing. BTW, if I have to do some ADB code, that's fine :). Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just had to uninstall the updates, and re update it from the Play Store.